# Proving a Fourier Polynomial Relation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, fourier-analysis, induction

Let $\phi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be $2\pi$-periodical function with $\phi|_{[-\pi,\pi[}= 1$

Prove $\forall N \in \mathbb N$ with $|x|<2\pi$ the fourier polynomial $F_{N}\phi$ satisfies:

$$(F_{N}\phi)(x+\pi)=x-\int^{x}_{0}\frac{\sin{[(N+1/2)t]}}{\sin{(t/2)}}dt$$

Steps so far:

First looking at the fourier coefficients $c_{k}$ for  $\phi$, we've got:

By definition $$c_{k}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}f(x)e^{-ikx}dx$$ and through partial integration we get:

$$c_{k}=\frac{\cos(k\pi)}{-ik}=\frac{(-1)^{k}}{-ik}$$

Now, looking at the Fourier polynomial, defined as:

$$(F_{N}\phi)(x)=\sum^{N}_{k=-N}c_{k}e^{-ikx}$$

That means:

$$(F_{N}\phi)(x)=\sum^{N}_{k=-N}(-1)^{k}\frac{e^{-ikx}}{-ik}$$

and since $c_{0}=0$;

$$(F_{N}\phi)(x)=\sum^{N}_{k=1}(-1)^{k}\frac{e^{-ikx}}{-ik}+\sum^{-1}_{k=-N}(-1)^{k}\frac{e^{-ikx}}{-ik}$$

It therefore follows that:

\begin{align}
(F_{N}\phi)(x+\pi)&=\sum^{N}_{k=1}(-1)^{k}\frac{e^{-ik(x+\pi)}}{-ik}+\sum^{-1}_{k=-N}(-1)^{k}\frac{e^{-ik(x+\pi)}}{-ik}\\
&=\sum^{N}_{k=1}(-1)^{2k}\frac{e^{-ikx}}{-ik}+\sum^{-1}_{k=-N}(-1)^{2k}\frac{e^{-ikx}}{-ik}\\
&=\sum^{N}_{k=1}\frac{e^{-ikx}}{-ik}+\sum^{-1}_{k=-N}\frac{e^{-ikx}}{-ik}
\end{align}

This is where I stop and I now have no idea how to get it back into integrals, let alone proving anything. Does the $\forall N \in \mathbb N$ suggest induction as a means of proving?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The trigonometric polynomial is obtained by a technique usinge the so-called Dirichlet kernel, which is periodic and has the very similar closed form. The partial sum of the trigonometric polynomial approximation equals the convolution of the original function with Dirichlet kernel of order $N$.